Cannot open xls file using Python in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2
I have the following code:
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
coordinates = r"C:\Tiedostot\folder1\coordinates.xls\Sheet1$"
print(arcpy.Exists(coordinates))
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(coordinates, ["X", "Y", "X2", "Y2"])

and I get the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
RuntimeError: cannot open 'C:\Tiedostot\folder1\coordinates.xls\Sheet1$'

The file path should definitely be right, and print(arcpy.Exists(coordinates)) gives False. What can I do to make this work?

Your code works fine for me and exists() returns true.

Nice to hear; for me it doesn't.

Does the python user have permission to read the file

XLS is an obsolete format, banned on a lot of Windows systems now. Did you try converting to XLSX?
